# How to do a list comprehension taking first a list then a dict in python

Tags: python

I have the following string that I'm trying to parse into a dict of k,v

> foo = "abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar"

I can achieve this with some really ugly code

```
foo_dict = {}
bar = foo.split(';') 
for item in bar:
  x = item.split('=')
foo_dict[x[0]] = x[1]
```

I'd much prefer this be a simple 1 line list comprehension.

Comment: Take care to remove the space that follows each semi-colon, or it will be part of the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs) module:

```
In [1] import urlparse
In [2] foo = "abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar"
In [3]: urlparse.parse_qs('abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar')
Out[3]: 
     {' defg': ['6cab'],
      ' rando': ['random'],
      ' token': ['foobar'],
      'abc': ['foo.bazz']}

In [4]: dict(urlparse.parse_qsl('abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar'))
Out[4]: {' defg': '6cab', ' rando': 'random', ' token': 'foobar', 'abc': 'foo.bazz'}
```

Not sure if you wanted those blank values in keys or not, but obviously easy to clean.

Comment: tbh I think this is very simple logic that anyone who calls them selves a programmer should be able to implement... its like saying you should use `np.transpose(matrix)` instead of `zip(*matrix)`

Answer (score 4):

```
dict(part.split("=") for part in foo.split(";"))
```

i think would work

```
>>> foo = "abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar"
>>> dict(part.split("=") for part in foo.split(";"))
{' token': 'foobar', 'abc': 'foo.bazz', ' defg': '6cab', ' rando': 'random'}
>>>
```

if you do `part.strip().split("=")` it may get rid of the extra spaces...

```
>>> dict(part.strip().split("=") for part in foo.split(";"))
{'token': 'foobar', 'abc': 'foo.bazz', 'defg': '6cab', 'rando': 'random'}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [107]: foo = "abc=foo.bazz; defg=6cab; rando=random; token=foobar"

In [115]:  dict(map(str.strip,x.split('=')) for x in foo.split(';'))
   .....: 
Out[115]: {'abc': 'foo.bazz', 'defg': '6cab', 'rando': 'random', 'token': 'foobar'}
```

Comment: Minor comment: I might add a .strip() to the key

Comment: @ToranBillups go for Joran's answer, he was 9 second faster.

Comment: I think you can actually just strip x to get rid of the spaces (although its probably better to map it so it gets spaces on either side of the =

Comment: @JoranBeasley you're right, `strip()` without `map()` was enough in this case, but `map()` might come in handy in case when there's space between `=` and the text.